# How to login local machine and change system parameter when use docker for mac

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I use docker for mac and  did create any other vm after install.

And I use [spujadas/elk-docker](https://github.com/spujadas/elk-docker) to run elk.

The log shows `vm.max_map_count is too low`.

So my question is how to change it on local vm?

docker-machine can not list any local machine.

So i can't ssh to local vm and modify it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is the code problem in this question?

Comment: May be I should ask " How to ssh to local machine if I use  docker for Mac"

Comment: I believe I have answer your "ssh to local machine" question below

Answer (score 1):

The [troubleshooting section](https://github.com/spujadas/elk-docker/blob/e15fcd3792529997eb866d693a0a95c9ddd9289b/docs/index.md#troubleshooting-) mentions:

> In particular, the message max virtual memory areas `vm.max_map_count [65530]` likely too low, increase to at least `[262144]` means that the host's limits on `mmap` counts must be set to at least `262144`.
>
> Use `sysctl vm.max_map_count` to view the current value, and see **[Elasticsearch's documentation on virtual memory](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/vm-max-map-count.html#vm-max-map-count)** for guidance on how to change this value.

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

> **Note that the limits must be changed on the host; they cannot be changed from within a container**.

You can ssh to the default machine with `docker-machine ssh` (which must exist if you ever run any container).

See [Install Elasticsearch with Docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html):

---

> ### OSX with Docker Toolbox
>
> The `vm_max_map_count` setting must be set via `docker-machine`:

```
docker-machine ssh
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

---

If you have [docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/#/the-docker-for-mac-environment) and its whyve VM, see [this thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/is-it-possible-to-ssh-to-the-xhyve-machine/17426/5):

```
screen
~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
```

To exit:

```
CTRL+A CTRL+\ followed by "y"
```

You will see a similar recommendation in "[Install Elasticsearch with Docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html)":

> The `vm_max_map_count` setting must be set within the xhyve virtual machine:

```
$ screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
```

> Log in with `root` and no password.
> Then configure the sysctl setting as you would for Linux:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Comment: I think your answer is for Docker machine, not native docker for mac.

Comment: @BMW Exactly. Because the OP mentioned docker-machine.

Comment: @BMW But I have added a way to enter the xhyve session, if we are talking about docker for mac

Comment: Yes, now it makes sense.

Comment: @BMW thanks ,it's helpfull